# BitVector32 - first bit true

Tags: c#, .net, bitvector

I am a bit puzzled with BitVector32 behaviour. See the test:

```
[TestClass]
public class ParallelPortDevices {
    [TestMethod]
    public void BitVector32Test() {
        var lVector = new BitVector32(0);

        Assert.IsTrue(lVector[0]);
        Assert.IsFalse(lVector[1]);
    }
}
```

This passes. I.e. the first bit is set to 1 (according to the test). However if you run the ToString method you will get "BitVector32{00000000000000000000000000000000}"

Anything I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The indexers indicate a bitmask, not an index.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`BitVector32` does not use the indexer syntax for index, it uses it as a bitmask. For example, if you were to do this:

```
lVector[7] = true;
```

`ToString` would give `0...000111`.

The decompiled code for the getter looks like this:

```
return ((long) this.data & (long) bit) == (long) (uint) bit;
```

So what ends up happening is this:

```
(0 & 0) == 0
```

Which of course, is true.